# Running counts of records and sum of max() records within date range based specified intervals in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

Sample data: (assume year_month_record is the first day of the month and is datetime data type)

```
location    item        year_month_record   type    visits1   visits2
ABC111      11JF445553  2014-01             sales   3         5
ABC111      11JF445553  2014-02             sales   3         6
ABC111      11JF445553  2014-03             sales   2         8
ABC111      11JF445553  2014-04             sales   2         4
ABC111      22WZ777814  2014-02             sales   3         5
ABC111      55RR342013  2014-01             nsales  1         2
```

For the given sample data, I need to count how many times records with the same location and item appear within specified intervals. In addition, I need to grab the maximum value for specified interval / time frame and sum it up based on location, item_number and type.

The output should look something like this:

```
location    year_month_record   length_months   type    count_unique_visits sum_max_visits1 sum_max_visits2
ABC111      2014-01             3               sales   4                   6               13
ABC111      2014-02             3               sales   4                   6               12
ABC111      2014-03             3               sales   2                   4               12
ABC111      2014-04             3               sales   1                   2               4
ABC111      2014-01             3               nsales  1                   1               2
```

*notes for calculating visits1 / visits2 above*

1. example output of record 1: max(of item 11JF445553) = 3 + max(item 22WZ77781) = 3.  Sum = 6 (item 55RR342013 has a different type).  Note 2.  All records with max summed up are within "length_months" specified of 3 months.  2014-01 through 2014-03.
2. new "type" will cause new grouping to start

Additional notes:

1. count_unique_visits is the count for each record within date range
2. length_months is defined prior to execution and can be hardcoded
3. current year_month_record + length_months (i.e. 2014-01 year_month_record with length_months = 3) is 01/2014 through 03/2014

I've tried creating a recursive CTE to select the count and max, but i'm doing something wrong.

Basically, I need to be able to recursively, grab a count and the max visit1/2 for a given interval.

Starting with 01/2014, it would need to look for the max(visits1/2) for the next three months (basically, 01/2014 - 04/2014) and return those.  In 02/2014, it would use the range of 02/2014 through 05/2014 and return the max there as well.  It would continue this throughout the recordset.  The interval would be 3 months, but then I could copy the query and replace with 6 months and so on and so forth.

Closing this topic to ask a more targeted/specific question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you storing `year_month_record`? What is its datatype?

Comment: year_month_record is simply a shortened version of the first day of the month, so it can be assumed as datetime if necessary.

Comment: Okay, I've read through your notes and looked at your data & expected results several times, now.  And I still don't see how you're coming up with some of your expected results.  Perhaps if you clarify things a little more?   (as a side note, have you tried multiple CTEs, each calculating an aggregate for its group, then joining your CTEs with your main query?)

Comment: I have a solution that I belive is correct, but it DOESN'T match some of your calculations (sum_max_visits2 rows 2 & 3 are 13 & 8 repspectively). Are you sure your calculations are correct (If so, please explain those values)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a groupping subquery followed by a cross apply subquery:

```
DECLARE @len int = 3

SELECT grp.*, SUM(ca.cuv) count_unique_visits, SUM(ca.visits1) sum_max_visits1, SUM(ca.visits2) sum_max_visits2
FROM
(SELECT v.location, v.year_month_record, v.type
 FROM Visits v
 GROUP BY v.location, v.year_month_record, v.type) grp CROSS APPLY
(SELECT COUNT(*) cuv, MAX(visits1) visits1, MAX(visits2) visits2
 FROM Visits ca_v
 WHERE ca_v.location = grp.location AND grp.type = ca_v.type AND ca_v.year_month_record >= grp.year_month_record AND
    ca_v.year_month_record < DATEADD(month, @len, grp.year_month_record)
 GROUP BY ca_v.item
 ) ca
GROUP BY grp.location, grp.year_month_record, grp.type
ORDER BY grp.type DESC, grp.year_month_record
```

You can see the results in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ce44/40).

*NOTE: As I wrote in the comment to the original question, I suspect you have a mistake in the requested output, if not, please explain...*